# ¿Por qué aparece el error TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list?

Tags: python

En cuanto a la duda esquematización intento usar el método `.join`, pero no sé por qué no me arranca. Me sale un

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

En cambio si no utilizo el `.join` en la función y lo utilizo fuera de la función, cuando empieza a llamarlo, me va correcto. Querría poder entender por qué no puedo usar el `.join` dentro de la función.

```
def inversa(a):

  lista = []
  for i in a:
     lista.append(i)

  if lista == []:
     return lista
  else:
     b = [lista[-1]] + inversa(lista[:-1])

  b2 = "".join(b)
     return b2

a = "palabra"
resultado = inversa(a)
print(resultado)
```

Como decía, si no utilizo el `.join` dentro de la función y lo uso fuera, en la llamada no hay problema.

```
def inversa(a):
  lista = []
  for i in a:
     lista.append(i)

  if lista == []:
     return lista
  else:
     b = [lista[-1]] + inversa(lista[:-1])

  return b

a= "palabra"
print(inversa(a))
lista2=(inversa(a))
b2 = "".join(lista2)
print(b2)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que es una función recursiva. En su nivel más profundo, el `return` del `else` no retorna a la *llamada del exterior*, si no a la propia función `inversa()` que se llamó a si misma, la cual está esperando una lista para concatenar con otra.

Pero como le estás mandando una cadena (ya que pusiste que retornara `"".join(b)`), al tratar de encadenar eso con la lista, obtienes el error.

```python
b = [lista[-1]] + inversa(lista[:-1])
#    ^-- lista     ^-- Cadena => "".join(b)
```

La solución es eliminar la línea `b2 = "".join(b)`, modificar `return b` y convertir en cadena la lista resultante, tal como lo tienes en el segundo código.

---

Como las cadenas de comportan de forma muy similar a las listas, puedes reducir algo la complejidad del mismo si solo usas cadenas y sus propiedades:

```python
def inversa(a):
    cadena = ''
    for i in a:
        cadena += i
    if cadena == '':
        return cadena
    else:
        return cadena[-1] + inversa(cadena[:-1])

a = "palabra"
resultado = inversa(a)
print(resultado)
```

---

Finalmente, no está de más decir que también está la vieja, confiable y recomentable:

```python
print(a[::-1]) # arbalap
```